# Extjs - validation of dependent fields

Tags: extjs

I use http://www.developersnippets.com/2009/06/24/date-range-using-extjs-date-field-and-advanced-vtype/ to check validation of dependent fields. It works. But if I remove text from data fields and let them empty, it requires to add correct data. I need validation only if one of the fields is not empty. If both fields are empty, let to submit. I set allowBlank:true.

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna have to work with a custom [validator](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator) to solve that problem.

Assuming you are working with ExtJS 4:

```
var from = Ext.create('Ext.form.Date', {
    name: 'from',
    ...
});
```

Just reference the dependent field onto the other one:

```
var to = Ext.create('Ext.form.Date', {
    name: 'to',
    validator: function(value) {
        if(from.getValue() == null && value == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Dosn't work. Says: Object doesn't support this property or method.